# How can I align these list elements with some buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to align some list elements that are created via Javascript with their corresponding buttons. Every time I add a new element to the list, the text appears in a lower position than the "X/Remove element" buttons. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You can check the pen right here:

https://codepen.io/Watashi10/pen/RwwQegr

The ideal thing would be to have the list elements and the X buttons in the same line or at the same height under the "input" element.

[Here is a screenshot of the actual list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDfms.png)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="text-center col-12">
                <h1 id="header">My Shopping List</h1>
            </header>
            <input class="text-center col-6" id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="add items">
            <section class="row">
                <button id="enter">Enter</button>
            </section>
            <div class="text-center col-12" id="shopping">
                <ul class="list" style="list-style: none">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; 
  background: url("https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/5/6/5/68320.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 15vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}


#header {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great';
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 5rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 25px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

input, button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.userinput {
  float: left;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great';
  color:#FFB6C1;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great';
  font-size: 25px;
  color:  #ffffff;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: I can tell you that `input, button{ bottom: 50px; }` creates a problem. Also, you should really use a much smaller image for a background, or just use [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the bottom: 50px from

```
input, button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px; //remove this
}
```

or if you want input to have bottom: 50px; seperate the css styling of them.

```
input {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15px !important; //just to make it a little nicer
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Now it works. Do you know how can I separate the element from the button?

Comment: You mean give it a little space between text and the button? thats with margin-left: 15px !important;   on the button

Comment: Yeah, now it looks much better with the space between the text and the button. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. But try to use classes to be more specific on which button you want to style. in this case you are styling every button on the page with each design change you make.

Answer (score 0):

So you're creating a textnode from the user input box here:

```js
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
```

I would recommend making this a div or a p or something else that can be styled.  Like so:

```js
let inputValue = document.createElement('div');
inputValue.innerHTML = input.value;
li.prepend(inputValue)
    input.value = "";
```

So you're li sctucture should look more like this:

```html
<li>
  <div class="value"></div>
  <button></button>
</li>
```

After that, theres many ways to have these be inline.  You could style the `li` to have a `display: flex`, or you could float the `button` to the right within the `li`.  But I would start with making the value that you catch and put into the li something besides just the textNode.